# Enabling a back button to update the email ID after the user clicks on Register in self-registration-with-verification.jsp

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I'm using Identity server version 5.10 fresh package, here I want to make customization where in the Self Registration process when

1. The user enters the firstname, lastname email id and other fields and click on the Self Register button, a confirmatiom link is sent to the specified email address and the pop up for the same appears.

But my requirement here is, I have a negative scenario,

2. where in the user enters a wrong email id during Self Registration process and clicks on the Self Register Button. Therefore the user will not be able to confirm his account as he has entered invalid email ID and i have also enabled user account lock on creation as well.

In which back end code of wso2 identity server should i make changes so that i can enable a back button, where in the user after getting the confirmation email sent pop up can go back to registration page and update his valid email again, so that he can get the confirmation link. Can Anyone from WSO2 team, please help

Comment: Are you allowing the user to set the email as their username? or else can they set a different username except the email? Even though you improve the self-registration flow by giving a back button there will be an issue of creating a second user with the same username. Or else are you expecting to give exiting user's email editing through the back button?. This could lead to security loophole

Comment: Hi @AnuradhaKarunarathna, I'm not enabling email as username here, also can I have an 1. option of enabling the back button to the user to change the username also. 2. If option 1 is not possible, what is the best possible option to proceed with, But I should enable a back button to the user if in case he enters wrong email id and clicks on register Button.

Comment: Kindly help with the best possible Solution